# Pass context from Custom View to a class

Tags: android, class, kotlin

I read that is bad practice to call invalidate() inside the onDraw method so i want to be able to call invalidate() from my Ball class to the onDraw method that is on the Game class.

In another post i read that creating an object of the Game class and then calling that object like gameClass.invalidate() is the best way to do it and im trying to figure out how to do that.

Im having trouble passing the context and attrs.

Here is my CustomView class:

```
class Game(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, 
attrs){

private val ball1 = Ball(width/2 - 50.toDouble(),150.0,20.0)

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    canvas.apply {

        drawOval((width / 2) - 50,
            ball1.posy.toFloat() - 50f,
                (width / 2)  + 50,
            ball1.posy.toFloat() + 50f,
                circleColor)
           }

        ball1.update()
}
```

Here is the class where i need to call invalidate:
is there a better way to call invalidate() here

val gameClass = Game(  how do i pass the context and attrs here?   )

```
class Ball(var posx: Double, var posy:Double,var velocity: Double){

//how do i pass the context and attrs here?
val gameClass = Game(...)    

fun update(){        
    posy += 10
    gameClass.invalidate()
}

}
```

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<view android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      class="com.example.myapplication.Game"
      id="@+id/view4"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing ?

Comment: i dont know how to pass the context and attrs inside Game:  val gameClass = Game(...)

Comment: pass the context to `Ball` class constructor and then pass to `Game` class. Whatever you need to pass to `Game` pass that first to `Ball` then to `Game`.

Comment: sorry im still trying to learn, how do i do that?

Comment: The constructor you are using(Context, AttributeSet) is called when inflated from xml, not at RunTime

Comment: @joacoooo323 just pass it to `Ball` constructor the same way you are passing to `Game` constructor. See answer.

Comment: It is Not the Ball that should be in Game ? (Architecture is up to you), but you could put Ball into Game and add an addBall() and update() method to Game

Comment: @joacoooo323 I have updated my answer kindly take a look, I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay first things first. It maybe a typo in your question but according to your code `Game` class is instantiating a `Ball` object and `Ball` class is instantiating a `Game` object. This is called [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) and you don't want this because it will result in `StackOverFlow` error (Ironic isn't it ?). So remove the `Game` object from `Ball` class.

Secondly, since you are calling `ball1.update()` inside `onDraw()` so calling `invalidate()` inside `ball1.update()` is no different than calling it after `ball1.update()`. In both cases you are calling `invalidate()` inside `onDraw()`.

The purpose of `invalidate()` is to tell the view to redraw itself whenever we change any data related to the view. Since you are changing the data related to view inside `onDraw()` by calling `ball1.update()` so calling `invalidate()` right after it would be the logical step to take. Like this and it will work in your case.

```
class Game(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet): View(context,attributes) {

    private val paint :Paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val ball1 = Ball(width/2 - 50.toDouble(),150.0,20.0)

    init{
        paint.color = Color.CYAN
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.apply {
            drawOval(
                (width / 2) - 50f,
                ball1.posy.toFloat() - 50f,
                (width / 2)  + 50f,
                ball1.posy.toFloat() + 50f,
                paint)

            ball1.update()
            invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

But `onDraw()` is not the best place to call `invalidate()`. There are many performance related issues so it is better to leave `onDraw()` alone.

Read here:

- https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK2i7ivzK7M

I'm assuming you want to animate your view. So it will be better to read the docs on [animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview).

But anyway let's continue. If you want to avoid calling `invalidate()` from `onDraw()` but still want to achieve the same result. Your best bet would be to create another function inside `Game` class which will start the process of updating your `Ball` object and calling `invalidate()` continuously. I'm naming this method as `startAnimation()`

This is how we can do this. Since your view is running on the UI Thread we need to get a `Handler` to it and tell the UI to run a [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) continuously by using `Handler.post()`. That `Runnable` will contain the code that will update your `Ball` object and call `invalidate()`. Luckily the `View` class itself contains `post()` method which is the same as `Handler.post()` so we can safely call this method inside our `Game` class because `Game` inherits `View`.

Here is the code :

```
class Game(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet): View(context,attributes) {

    private lateinit var runnable : Runnable // reference to the runnable object
    private val ball1 = Ball(width/2 - 50.toDouble(),150.0,20.0)
    private val paint :Paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    //This is the constructor of the class
    init{
        paint.color = Color.CYAN

        //Here we initialize our Runnable and put the code that we want to run once we call startAnimation()
        runnable = Runnable {
            ball1.update()
            invalidate()

            //Calling post() inside here will loop the above code and you will see a smooth animation
            post(runnable)
        }
    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.apply {
            drawOval(
                (width / 2) - 50f,
                ball1.posy.toFloat() - 50f,
                (width / 2)  + 50f,
                ball1.posy.toFloat() + 50f,
                paint)
        }
    }

    //This is the new function I am talking about
    fun startAnimation()
    {
        post(runnable)
    }

    fun stopAnimation()
    {
        removeCallbacks(runnable)
    }

}
```

And we start the animation by calling `startAnimation()` from **MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val game = findViewById<Game>(R.id.view)
        game.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

To stop the animation just call `stopAnimation()`

Read more about processes, threads and handler here :

- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

Comment: The Constructor with AttributeSet shall be used if he set his Game View in xml.. as you probably know, the Constructor with just Context as parameter is more appropriate

Comment: @UserOne You maybe correct but I'm answering from programming perspective, considering `Game` and `Ball` as separate classes that he wrote. We don't know yet whether there is any actual view defined in XML or not related to these classes or what purpose he is using these classes for.

Comment: Of course, but as he stated he's new and thus he think he need to pass both to instantiate his Game View, from where he will get AttributeSet when instantiating Ball ? I think it's a misuse of this constructor, i think the constructor with just Context is more appropriate, and Yes we know, because he try to instantiate the Game View so probably not defined in xml

Comment: True. Well it is upto him to clarify that or accept your suggestion

Comment: i updated the post being more clear and with more code, i think this will work but do i need to create a secondary constructor because with this i need to pass the context and attrs every time i create a new ball? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @joacoooo323 I think I misunderstood what you are really asking for. You want to call `invalidate()` method after you update your 'Ball' object right ? Do you want your ball to be just moving indefinitely or your ball will move based on some action ? Whatever your reason maybe you can still call `invalidate()` after `ball1.update()` since your canvas data has been updated. They discourage to call `invalidate()` in `onDraw()` because canvas is drawing at that time and not being updated. Since you are updating you can call `invalidate()` after `ball1.update()`

Comment: @joacoooo323 also calling `invalidate()` inside `ball1.update()` method using a `Game` class object makes no difference because it will still be inside `onDraw()` because `ball1.update()` is inside `onDraw()`. Just do it like this `ball1.update() invalidate()`

Comment: "Theorically" calling his update() and thus invalidate() inside onDraw() will create an infinite loop, because invalidate() call onDraw() and onDraw() he recall invalidate(), it look like what he's trying to do is an animation where the Ball move, so maybe an Object/ValueAnimator is the right thing to go

Comment: And also a suggestion if using the Handler way, postDelayed()